# Why does function return type need to be of type (void*) for threading in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

In c, we create a thread like so:

```
void * run(void * arg){
    printf("hello world\n");
}

int main(){
    pthread_t thread;
    int a = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, run, (void*)0);
}
```

But it will not work if I declare run as

```
void run(){}
```

On the other hand, if I cast it to `(void *)` in the parameter of `pthread_create`, it works fine. So it only accepts functions with return types of `(void *)`.

Why?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my system, `man pthread_create` says:

> If `start_routine` returns, the effect is as if there was an implicit call to `pthread_exit()`, using the return value of `start_routine` as the exit status.

This return value is available through the `pthread_join()` function:

> On return from a successful `pthread_join()` call with a non-NULL `value_ptr` argument, the value passed to `pthread_exit()` by the terminating thread is stored in the location referenced by `value_ptr`.

Comment: So, the `start_routine`'s returned (void) pointer points to what would otherwise be a straightforward returned value from the routine, to be used, if required, after the `pthread_join` call?

Comment: ... it basically enables you to return a value from the thread to the main process, doesn't it?

Answer (score 6):

The thread function must be declared to return `void *` because the threading library expects such a return value, and will store it into a location given to `pthread_join()` after the thread terminates.

If you don't need the thread return value for anything, you can just `return 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?  By definition, threads cannot be called or returned from because they have their own stack.  It's usually useful, however, to be able to signal some initial data to a thread and it is possible that signalling somethin out on thread termination might be useful too. The OS designers knew that and so allowed a fixed amount of data to be copied onto the thread stack at startup and signaled out on termination.  The OS thread calls have to be language-agnostic and hence the universal choice of one machine-width word.  C presents this as a void*, presumably to indicate that it's just some value with no type.